# Python: where is the method listdir because there is no "def listdir()" in module os.py?

Tags: python, cpython, listdir

Python: I wonder where this method listdir because he is not in the module os.py. In this module there is no a method:

```
def listdir ()
```

Comment: From os.py file: "# Note that `listdir` and `error` are globals in this module due to earlier `import-*`."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `listdir` method is actually implemented in a C module, and is imported dynamically depending on the operating system environment. You can see the imports near the top of `os.py`, in blocks like this :

```
if 'posix' in _names:
    name = 'posix'
    linesep = '\n'
    from posix import *
```

Then the file `posixmodule.c` in the Python source has the POSIX implementation of `listdir` : https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Modules/posixmodule.c#L2068 (and likewise for other OSes).